# Selenium is going back to the start of and for i in range(1, 5)

Tags: python, selenium, range

I have an in range problem.

```
 for i in range(1, 5):
     size_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="select-attr-1"]/span[2]/a[{i}]').click()
     size = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="select-attr-1"]/span[2]/a[{i}]').get_attribute("data-value")
     print(size)
     input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@class,'fl num logsss_event_cl')]").send_keys('99')
     sleep(3)
     plus_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="select-attr-1"]/span[2]/a[1]').click()
     sleep(5)
     inventory = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@class,'fl num logsss_event_cl')]").get_attribute("value")
     sleep(5)
     print(inventory)
```

It does the first {i} great no problem, then it mover to the second size does the operation except it goes back to the first {i} before it can record the inventory. which by default is set to 1.
So the first size invertory is correct but the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, and 5th are all 1's, no matter how high I set the sleep.

Comment: can you check you xpath for inventory? Where is the iterator?

Comment: So what is `{s}`?

Comment: The s should have been an {i}?

Comment: The way you get the available inventory is that you input 99 into the box and then click +.  Then it shows you what's available. I'll put in 99 in the input click the plus button and the available inventory pops up.